# Karma testing with .success() getting 'undefined' is not an object'

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm trying to write a unit test to see if the 'getStudents()' provider function in my controller gets called if some properties are appropriately set. Notice the .success() callback:

```
 $scope.update = function update() {
    // omitted, just doing some checking...
    // finally 
    else if (key.length === 3 || $scope.students.length === 0) {
       StudentsProvider.getStudents($scope.keyword, $scope.selectedFilters).success(function(data) {
           $scope.students = data;
       });
    }
 };
```

My karma unit test looks like this:

```
describe("Students: Controllers", function () {
    var $scope;
    var ctrl;
    beforeEach(module('studentsApp'));

    describe("SearchCtrl", function () {
        // Mock the provider
        var mockStudentsProvider = {
            getStudents: function getStudents() {
                return [
                    {
                         Education: [], 
                         Person: [{ 
                             ID: 1, 
                             Name: "Testing McTestsson", 
                             SSN: "1234567890",
                             Address: "Fakestreet 3", MobilePhone: "7777777"
                         }]
                    }
                ];
             }
         };
         var StudentsProvider;
         beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
             $scope = $rootScope.$new();
             ctrl = $controller('SearchCtrl', { $scope: $scope, StudentsProvider: mockStudentsProvider});
             StudentsProvider = mockStudentsProvider;
         }));
         describe("Update", function () {
             beforeEach(function () {
                 spyOn(StudentsProvider, 'getStudents');
             });
             it("should always call the provider with 3 letters", function () {
                 $scope.keyword = "axe";
                 $scope.update();
                 expect(StudentsProvider.getStudents).toHaveBeenCalled();
                 expect(StudentsProvider.getStudents).toHaveBeenCalledWith("axe", "");
             });
         });
    });
});
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'StudentsProvider.getStudents($scope.keyword, $scope.selectedFilters).success')
```

and it's probably because I'm not mocking the .success() callback. How would I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace this:

```
var mockStudentsProvider = {

    getStudents: function getStudents() {
        return [{
            Education: [],
            Person: [{
                ID: 1,
                Name: "Testing McTestsson",
                SSN: "1234567890",
                Address: "Fakestreet 3",
                MobilePhone: "7777777"
            }]
        }];
    }
};
```

with this:

```
var mockStudentsProvider = {
    getStudents: function getStudents() {
        var retVal = [{
            Education: [],
            Person: [{
                ID: 1,
                Name: "Testing McTestsson",
                SSN: "1234567890",
                Address: "Fakestreet 3",
                MobilePhone: "7777777"
            }]
        }];
        return {
            success: function(fn) {
                fn(retVal)
            };

        }
    }
};
```

And replace this:

```
spyOn(StudentsProvider, 'getStudents');
```

with this:

```
spyOn(StudentsProvider, 'getStudents').andCallThrough();
```

1. When you do not use `andCallThrough()` or `andCallFake()` jasmine prevents execution of the method and returns null. Inside your update method you are calling `null.success`. This will fail. (http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html)
2. In your mock method you need to change the return format--the real http method returns an object where success refers to a function which takes an input a callback function.

In your case, the callback function is:

```
function(data) {
   $scope.students = data;
}
```